# Edição fica bloqueada quando tem uma edição pendente a ser analisada?

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Eu estava tentando editar [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263140/estiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-views-laravel). Quando eu tento clicar no botão "editar", pelo fato de ter uma edição pendente para análise, sempre abre a janela de aprovação da edição... MAS EU QUERO É EDITAR!

Veja o que acontece quando clico no "editar":

[image: Edição teimosa]

Como eu posso fazer isso?

---

## English Version

**Title:** Edit blocked if there's a pending suggested edit?

I was trying to edit [this question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263140/estiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-views-laravel). When I click "edit," I get redirected to the suggested edit review modal, because there's a pending suggested edit... but what I want to do is edit it!

Here's what happens when I click "edit:"

[image]

How can I just edit?

Answer (score 5):

Acabei descobrindo fuçando o site aqui.

É só acessar a url `/posts/{id_da_pergunta}/edit` que você consegue editar.

Agora, eu não sei qual é o impacto que isso poderia causar caso a edição seja aprovada depois que eu fiz a minha edição.

Comment: Eu suspeito que isso tenha o mesmo efeito que o "melhorar" - que era a opção que você devia ter escolhido no momento da análise...

Comment: Mais parecido com "rejeitar e editar," mas é isso.